# Python: how to stall execution of function until two threads complete

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm new enough to python programming and starting to dabble with concurrency for the first time, so please forgive any terms.

My programme starts two threads with each call a function "lightshow()" but rather than the programme stalling it's execution until both threads have completed it moves on to the next line in the code.

Is it possible to "pause" the progamme until both threads have completed?

Below is my code snippet:

```
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread

# Handshake pulse on GPIO2 of 4 50ms highs

def setup():
        for pulse in range(5):
                hs.on()
                sleep(0.05)
                hs.off()
                sleep(0.05)
        print('handshake comlete')

def lightshow(sequence, relay):
        t_end = time.time() + 60*1
        while time.time() < t_end:
                print('starting timer')
                # iterate over the dictionary's keys and values 
                for key, value in sequence.items():
                        relay.on()
                        sleep(key)
                        relay.off()
                        sleep(value)



setup() #send handshake to board to prime it.


t1 = threading.Thread(target = lightshow, args=(flickerRGB, relay1))
t2 = threading.Thread(target = lightshow, args=(flickerWhite, relay2))

t1.start()
t2.start()

#send handshake to Relay board to reset it
setup()
```

Basically the programme switches two relays simultaneously to switch on lights with different on/off patterns.

If there's a better way other than threading please let me know.

Many thanks,

Paul

Comment: Don't you want to do setup before the two threads?

Comment: yes, setup() sends a pulse train to the relay board to prime it so the relays can be accessed, also setup() is called at the end of the programme to reset the relay board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#send handshake to Relay board to reset it
t2.join() #block until thread exits
setup()
```

but since its just a hardcoded timeout why not just

```
time.sleep(61)
```

Comment: Hi Joran, thank you for the help. I understand the first answer but don't follow   "but since its just a hardcoded timeout why not just

time.sleep(61)"  can you explain for the newbie please?

Comment: @Tullio_IRL - both threads are running a while loop that will finish after 60 seconds. So, both threads can be assumed to have finished by the 61 second mark.

Comment: Okay, I get it now, so just add the "time.sleep(61)" after the threads have started, thank you sir :)